# Is it possible to import only the jar files of a library project. For example: Aviary, telerik, facebook

Tags: android, eclipse, telerik

Is it possible to import only the jar files of a library project. For example: Aviary, telerik etc.

I am using the above features in my project. While i have done the samples i have to import the SDK projects into our workspace. Can we import only the jar files into our projects and use the above features in our app?

Comment: Try to put those jar in your project lib folder and check but might be some library required style in those case you have to import sdk instead of jar.

Comment: what type of library you are referring to for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy those jar from a library project to your lib 
or
Right click on project-> properties -> java build path -> add jar -> project source lib project->lib->select jar ->ok->ok.

Answer (score 0):

Hi #Jafeena for facebook 3.14 this is not allowed.

whats the problem, why not to add all of them as a library, if problem is related to same name then change library name with Eclipse->refractor functionality and use them as your library.